# SQL Server express service is not starting

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I've bought my first VPS yesterday, and I have installed *Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express* on it.

Then I have restarted my VPS. But SQL Server Service didn't start. I've tried to start it manually, but It can't start:

[image: SQL Server service doesn't start]

What is the problem? How to solve it?

P.S: This is my first server management, and I'm a newbie, if you need any further details about this, please leave a comment. I'll update the question.

**Update 1:** This is some log details from Event viewer that I thought that they may be useful for this problem:

> FCB::Open failed: Could not open file
>   e:\sql11_main_t.obj.x86release\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\MSDBData.mdf
>   for file number 1.  OS error: 3(The system cannot find the path
>   specified.).
>
> The resource database build version is 11.00.3000. This is an
>   informational message only. No user action is required.
>
> FileMgr::StartLogFiles: Operating system error 2(The system cannot
>   find the file specified.) occurred while creating or opening file
>   'e:\sql11_main_t.obj.x86release\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\MSDBLog.ldf'. Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the
>   operation.
>
> Starting up database 'model'.
>
> FCB::Open failed: Could not open file
>   e:\sql11_main_t.obj.x86release\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\model.mdf
>   for file number 1.  OS error: 3(The system cannot find the path
>   specified.).
>
> FileMgr::StartLogFiles: Operating system error 2(The system cannot
>   find the file specified.) occurred while creating or opening file
>   'e:\sql11_main_t.obj.x86release\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\modellog.ldf'.
>   Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the
>   operation.

I'm confused about these `e:\`s, my VPS has just one C:\ drive, So what is e:\ ?

Comment: look at the logs, like the error message said. Go to event viewer and have a take it from there.

Comment: @Sc0rian Question updated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There a few [topics](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/88e179a4-91d7-4608-8932-bcc8796ec107/) on it, but someone posted a good workaround [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/54bbcac3-41c5-4a5d-a4f6-2669e538dc82/)

```
NET START MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS /f /T3608

SQLCMD -S .\SQLEXPRESS

1>SELECT name, physical_name, state_desc FROM sys.master_files ORDER BY database_id;

Now notice those wrong file names; and run following commands ...

Note: you need to change the file name location ..

1>ALTER DATABASE model MODIFY FILE ( NAME = modeldev, FILENAME = 'c:\model.mdf');
2>ALTER DATABASE model MODIFY FILE ( NAME = modellog, FILENAME = 'c:\modellog.ldf');
3> go

ALTER DATABASE msdb MODIFY FILE ( NAME = MSDBData, FILENAME = 'c:\MSDBData.mdf');
ALTER DATABASE msdb MODIFY FILE ( NAME = MSDBLog, FILENAME = 'c:\MSDBLog.ldf');

ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE ( NAME = tempdev, FILENAME = 'c:\temp.mdf');
ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE ( NAME = templog, FILENAME = 'c:\temp.ldf');

go

exit;

NET STOP MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
```

Comment: After running those commands, Now I'm getting these errors (in Event Viewer): `Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.) occurred while creating or opening file 'c:\modellog.ldf'. Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the operation.` How to **create** those `*.mdf`, `*.ldf` files?

Comment: There was `model, modellog, MSDBData and MSDBLog` files in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA`. Now the problem is solved. Thank you very much!

Comment: remmeber to enter "Go " in second line after first query to execute it

Comment: for me for some reason MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS or SQL 2014 LocalDB express was replaced instead of old MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS path

Comment: I worked at this for a very long time, and couldn't get it right, basically I could start SQL with the first part, but after that SQLCMD couldn't connect using windows authentication. And if I used MSSMS the db engined tried to load it's resources db at that same bad location. 

My solution was to simply give the engine what it wants... created a RamDisk and that path and copied the system dbs to that location.  Now I can use MSSMS and set the paths to the correct values.