# SQL Server 2012 Database engine failed to install everytime

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to install SQL Server 2012 -64 bit in our dev server running Windows Server 2012. Everytime, Database engine fails to install. I've checked the event logs it shows.

Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.) occurred while creating or opening file 'e:\sql11_main_t.obj.x86release\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\modellog.ldf'. Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the operation.

I followed the link- [SQL Server express service is not starting](https://serverfault.com/questions/447808/sql-server-express-service-is-not-starting) to resolve the issue. I opened command prompt and run the command - NET START MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS /f /T3608

But it throws the error - The service name is invalid.

Has anyone gone through this issue. Please suggest a solution for this issue.

Thanks,

Kunal

Comment: Did id occur to you taht if you INSTALL it and it FAILS EVERY TIME - your install is corrupt? Get a new install image. Why do you think you ahve a "not starting" issue when the error message CLEARLY states that a file is missing AND NAMES THE FILE?

Comment: I have downloaded SQL Server 2012 Express from Microsoft site- https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=29062. Then also Database engine fails to install.

Comment: So, just because you download something (ONCE) means autoamtically that the download is done perfect? THAT is new to me - I had in the past quite often to repeat downloads because the downlaoded file was incomplete. In case of an archive this could mean when you extract it some files are missing.